# Engel Expansion Algorithm question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

For a positive real number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it's Engel expansion is a sequence of non decreasing positive integers $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$ such that $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_1a_2\dots a_k}$.

The Engel expansion Algorithm is as follows:

> Let $a_k=\lceil\frac{1}{u_k}\rceil$ where $u_k:=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }k=1\\u_{k-1}a_{k-1}-1&\text{otherwise }\end{cases}$, if for some $k$ we have that $u_k=0$ then the algorithm halts and we get the finite list $\{a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}\}$ for the Engel expansion, if not just consider the infinite sequence of the $a_k$.

It is clear to me that the algorithm gives me non decreasing rational numbers whose infinite sum converges.

It is not clear to me that it converges to $x$ and after trying it for a while I failed misserably...

Comment: Have you read [Erdos, Renyi, and Szusz](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1958-07.pdf)?

Comment: I did not had access, nor did I find that paper in my google searches. Is there a proof of my question in there? Do you know at which page? I've have not found one but I just skimmed it, I'm gonna keep reading tho.

Comment: I'd target the display inequality just before equation (1.1).

Comment: You say that the $a_i$ are rational, but per the algorithm, they are integer. Of course integer is rational, but I am curious about the disparity.

Comment: Yea they are positive integers I gave a wrong definition, edited.